# UI for finding files on mac

Tags: objective-c, macos

Maybe because I don't know the proper terminology I can not find anything on the internet regarding my question. What I want to achieve is a navigation window that opens on a button click (exactly the one we see when we let's say want to add files to the project and xCode gives us the option to search through the computer to find the file we want to add).

How exactly I can achieve this behaviour? If it is a duplicate, please comment and I will delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are searching for is called `NSOpenPanel`

Example usage:

```
- (NSInteger) showFilepanel{
    self.filePanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [self.filePanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];     //This will allow the user to select multiple files
    [self.filePanel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];        //If you want the user to select lets say a path to save a file, you should enable this so he can select the directory
    [self.filePanel setCanChooseFiles:YES];             // For selecting only files (like in an Open File-scenario)
    return [self.filePanel runModal]; //This will return 0 if the user cancelled
}
```

You can then read the selected path like this:

```
- (void) savePathFromPanel{
    NSString *path = [[self.panel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
    //Do now what you want with the selected path
}
```